# What do you think which are the best Gallery Viewer plugins from UX point of view? Why?

Tags: gui-design, viewer

Today I saw that Facebook has changed again it's gallery viewer but in my opinion it is still not the best!

- too slow
- too gray
- hard to distinguish from bakcground

I have seen many, much more convenient solutions in Wordpress... for example:
[image]

What do you think which are the best Gallery Viewer plugins from UX point of view? Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "plugins"? Scripts for web apps?

Comment: Hi Roland, I wonder if there's a better way to phrase this question so it's more focused on the *why*. See the StackExchange blog post on [shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: In my opinion lightboxes are misused a lot, a lightbox should be used to view a gallery of images. When a user intends to see an image it should not use a lightbox to view it. It interrupts the experience and the users flow.

Comment: Lightbox has usability issues. Check out [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/4947/947) to see why. So discussing which one is better is relatively pointless.

Comment: @Rahul for example wordpress plug-ins (so plug-ins for a CMS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this question really belongs here but I'll answer anyway:

For the kind of gallery you're referring to (overlay), I like **[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)**. It looks nice with standard settings, is customizable and easy to use (I've never done any user testing with it though). But I don't think there's any general solution - it really depends on your requirements.

And here's a collection with tons of galleries: [57+ Free Image Gallery, Slideshow And Lightbox Solutions](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)