# Using a lightbox as a new page

Tags: website-design

Hope i'm posting this on the right forum.

I'm designing myself a new portfolio website and had the idea of using a lightbox to display *about me* content. So, when the user clicks on *about me*, a lightbox will fade in with the about me content. As user experience specialists, what are your thoughts on this? Or is it best practice to be directed to another page or another part of the page and use lightboxes for strictly for galleries?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4947/the-usability-of-lightbox-uis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the context. If you are using the lightbox feature for all across your site, it's ok; BUT, if you can navigate from the menu, and each time you click its redirects you to another one and when you click "About me" and appears a modal / Lightbox / X, it lacks consistency.

When you use lightboxes or modals, you don't lose the original content.

A new page should not be show it in a lightbox if the context changes.

**Should: (just examples)**

- Quick ecommerce item view without all the information.
- Lightbox confirmation of sending the information or uploading a document.
- Blog post summary in a news site.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use lightboxes when an item appears on the screen and you need primary attention of it, like an alert, a quick reading (sneak peak of information) or a picture.

You can use it for maintaining the user in the same page without loosing context of it.