# What does a user expect tapping album artwork to do?

Tags: controls, input

I'm designing a music player app, which will play from a stream on the internet. In the app, I plan to show a navigation  bar, a tab bar, and some info about the song that the user is listening to.

In addition to viewing info, I'd the users to be able to stop/resume playback and have some way for them to see the song in iTunes or some external website.

Consider that I have two actions:

- Playback
- Launch External App

I seem to only have one place to put a button. I was thinking of making the album artwork into a button, but the next question is, which action gets a button, and which one gets the artwork? What do users expect? Do I simply put two buttons beneath the song info? Do I put one button in the right of the navigation bar?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On what a "user expects", it will depend on the *context*:

- In iTunes: play the album.
- In an MP3 shop: more info or add to cart.
- In a blog or bulletin thread: open image in a new tab.

In your case, **if the user is browsing around, opening an external app (iTunes) would [disrupt](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-research-is-there-suggesting-modal-dialogs-are-disruptive) his/her experience, so I'd recommend doing this action pretty obvious:** use a button that says `launch album in iTunes` or something similar. While tapping on the album would simply play the album, enabling the user to play/pause and continue browsing without interruptions.

Tapping on the album is already a common pattern, used by the iTunes iOS and Spotify Facebook apps. Affordance is normally conveyed with a a `play` and `pause` icon over the album art.

[image: cover flow]

Comment: Useless comment:  I never realized that the Impressionists also made music! :)

Comment: playing a painting, now that has to be synesthesic